# Cannot override properties of logback-spring.xml in config folder to other module's logback-spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback, properties-file

This is my first time using logging in spring and I was given a logback-spring.xml in config folder at root of maven project. I have 3 more modules in my project and all three having the same logback-spring.xml file in their src/main/resource path.

For eg. 
In projectStar/config/logback-spring.xml I have properties:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy 
         class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.zip</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>2KB</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
</appender>


    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
```

Having properties in projectStar/server/src/main/resource/logback-spring.xml:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
         <encoder>
             <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p %m%n</pattern>
         </encoder>
         <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
         <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
             <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.txt</fileNamePattern>
             <maxFileSize>1KB</maxFileSize>
             <maxHistory>2</maxHistory>
         </rollingPolicy>
</appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
```

There is yaml file also in which having properties like :

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: DEBUG

  file: log/a.log
  config: classpath:logback-spring.xml
```

Now when I am running server of project it is not overriding the properties from config logback file, taking from server resource logback file.
It is giving me file

> a.log.2018-04-06-21.0.txt

but I need file

> a.log.2018-04-06-21.0.zip

file.
I want like my log must be in zip format and 2 KB(as mentioned in config/logback-spring.xml file) in size, no matter what I give inside other modules. It always take first from config logback and if not found then it go to inside other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You should put the first logback-spring.xml in projectStar/server/src/main/resource/config, the file under /config will override the one in the /resource.

Comment: you mean that I should make a config folder under resource!

Comment: No it is not working. It still taking properties from  projectStar/server/src/main/resource/config first and not override properties from root /config folder.